# Disable Auto Restore from Google Backup in Android App Programatically

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, restore, backups

I am facing a problem which is huge for me, the problem is I have an app published on Google Play with a lot of user, the maintain its state now I have changed the state and app is crashing because users have enabled Android Auto Backup feature and app gets the state from Google Server which conflicts with newer version of my app.
Please tell me how can I disable Auto Restore feature from my app programmatically.
Thanks

Comment: If by "programmaticaly", you mean "at compile time", add `android:allowBackup="false"` to your `<application>` element in the manifest.

Comment: Will it stop restoring backups from Google server as well?

Comment: It is supposed to, yes.

Comment: I have checked its still restoring my app.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a fix?

Comment: Add the following line in your Main Manifest file in Manifest Tag

tools:replace="allowBackup" android:allowBackup="false"